# Using a rich text editor on mobile websites

Tags: android, html, mobile, rich-text-editor

I'm searching for a rich text editor (like TinyMCE or CKEditor) that supports smartphones and tablets.

I've tried TinyMCE and CKEditor on a HTML5 website and I couldn't use the editor at all. So I think there is no support for mobile in those two. Maybe I'm wrong and I have to configure something or maybe I just need to search another editor.

I'm testing this with both Android Emulators and Physical Devices.

Can someone recommend a good editor for mobile websites?

Comment: What version of Android?  Looks like [only Android browser v3](http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable) has support for the underlying `contenteditable`

Comment: We're targeting Android 2.3.4 and 3.0 right now. But hopefully the client is upgrading to Android 4 as soon as it's available. Probably there is a lot more support for such things?

Comment: If you look at my link you'll see it's specifically only v3 which has support.

Comment: Pretty strange. I thought it still would have to be changed. But you're saying Android 4 won't get any support at all? Too bad..

Comment: I've no idea what the future plans are for v4.  I'm just providing you with a link, you could go and read it yourself instead of asking me what it says.  If I had an answer I would have given one.

Comment: I've read it, already before my second comment. But I thought you had some more information about that.
I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. ;)